# getting values based on another field from json without iteration - angular js

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

How to get "value" from "name" from a json without iteration in `Angular JS`. For example I 've the following array with name and value field, how can I retrieve say "ABC" value based on name "a" without iteration in script?.

```
$scope.array = [{"name":"a","value":"ABC"},{"name":"b","value":"GHI"},{"name":"c","value":"EFG"}];
```

Can we do anything like this?

```
$scope.value = $scope.array.name["a"].value;
```

Comment: You can't. Either you or the library you choose will have to iterate through the list to examine it.

Comment: but this worked .....`$scope.array.filter(function(obj){ return (obj.name=="a"); })[0].value;//ABC`

Comment: Array.filter iterates through the list and applies the closure you provide. Still iteration. Why are you trying to avoid it?

Comment: if there are 1000 values iteration will slow down the process right....

Comment: You'd be surprised. But if speed is your real concern, now not only are you iterating through the list, you're adding the overhead of calling a closure on every entry. The only way to remove iterating through the list and examining it is to have the data sent to you another way, e. g. an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use filter instead of iterating:

```
$scope.array.filter(function(obj){ return (obj.name=="a"); })[0].value;//ABC
```

Although it also iterates over the array.

You can also use [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) with these kinds of case, it has a find function like this:

```
_.find($scope.array, function(item) {
    return item.name == "a";
});
```

But the point is, all these features, use kind of iteration to give you what you want.